# L'expression « présenter les mots »

Tags: sens, expressions

Je voudrais savoir ce que veut dire l'expression « présenter les mots » dans ce contexte :

> Suite à l’« essai de problématisation » et au chapitre premier où nous
>   présentions les mots, ferments du changement qui fondent ce débat, il nous a semblé opportun de commencer par identifier les problèmes majeurs de la société.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Présenter les mots* : essayer de les définir dans le contexte de l'exposé.

On définit l'acception choisie des mots les plus significatifs qui articulent la pensée qui soutient le texte.